# checkbox remove [checked] angular 2

Tags: angular

**HTML**

```
<div class="noteCheckBox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="noteCheckBox" [checked]="checkbox" (change)="stateCheckBox()">
        <label for="noteCheckBox" class="noteLabel">AnyText</label>
</div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from '../../services/cookie/cookie.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'pagCheckBox',
    templateUrl: './app/html/pagCheckBox.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/css/pagCheckBox.component.css']
})

export class PagCheckBox {

    constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.checkbox = this.cookieService.getCookie('checkbox');
    }

    stateCheckBox(event) {
        let state = $("#noteCheckBox").prop("checked"); //true or false
        this.checkbox = this.cookieService.setCookie('checkbox', state);
    }
 }
```

I have a `CookieService` which comprise information (from cookie browser) about state checkbox (`true` or `false`).

If `(checkbox == true)` then need to add attr `checked` in Html else to remove.

I tried to make `[checked]="checkbox"` and checkbox dynamic changes (`true` or `false`) and attr off or on but poorly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- to bind to attributes instead of properties use `[attr.fooAttr]`
- to get attributes removed assign `null` (`false` will add an attribute with value `"false"` but won't remove the attribute while with `null` Angular removes it from the DOM.

```
[attr.checked]="checkbox ? true : null"
```

Comment: Did you try my 2nd suggestion as well?

Comment: `checked` is available as a property and just works (without any of my suggestions) [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7ym8P0p8sXGC6x5wwy0v?p=preview). Perhaps the value returned from `this.cookieService.setCookie(...)` is not boolean but a string.

Comment: Yes, it's. Thank you. Just this.cookieService.setCookie(...) is not boolean but a string. Oh, this is JS )